# Add rows to a tableview from database

Tags: javascript, tableview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

i need append rows to a tableview reading data from database. My problem is all rows are mixed.

My code is

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('MyData');
var rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM TablaAuxiliar ORDER BY TablaAuxiliar.Nombre');

var i;
var nuevaRow=Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:80});

for (i=0;i<NRegistros;i++){

    var titulo=Ti.UI.createLabel({
        id: "NombreTerm",
        text: rows.field(2),
        color: "black" ,
        textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT, 
        left:20,
        top:5
    });
    var titulo2=Ti.UI.createLabel({
        id: "EstadoTerm",
        text: rows.field(3),
        font: {fontSize: '30'},
        color: "#888" ,
        textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT, 
        left:20,
        top:30
    });
    var titulo3=Ti.UI.createLabel({
        id: "TemperaturaTerm",
        text: rows.field(4)/10,
        font: {fontSize: '50'},
        color: "#888" ,
        textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT, 
        left:200,
        top:5
    });
    nuevaRow.add(titulo);
    nuevaRow.add(titulo2);
    nuevaRow.add(titulo3);
    $.MenuLateral.appendRow(nuevaRow);
    rows.next();
}       

db.close();
```

$.MenuLateral is the TableView created with Alloy

```
        <TableView id="MenuLateral" top="20%" height="60%" left="0%" zindex="20" width="100%" backgroundColor="white" separatorColor="gray">
        </TableView>
```

I need a row for each record in the database. Where is the problem??

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of the `NRegistros` variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move this line of code **var nuevaRow=Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:80});** inside the **for loop**.

Actually, you have created only a single TableViewRow variable and if you will use that same variable to appendRow, then it will be a single row only with having many labels added from inside **for loop**.

So just try this code:

```
var i;

for (i=0;i<NRegistros;i++){
    var nuevaRow=Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:80});
...
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant, You are rignt